# MD5 hash of a Amazon RedShift UDF

Tags: amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions, md5

I have a Redshift UDF such as given below. I need to check if this function is changed by checking its MD5 Hash against I guess the original hash and in that case delete and recreate this function again.

I am wondering how to generate a MD5 hash of a UDF. Thank you for help.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE formatter (decimal,varchar)
RETURNS varchar
VOLATILE
AS $$
SELECT
CASE
WHEN $2 IS NULL THEN TO_CHAR($1/1,'999999999999')
WHEN $2 = 'BIF' THEN TO CHAR($1/!,'999999999999')
.....
ELSE TO ...
END
$$ language sql
```

Struggling with calculating MD5 hash

Answer (score -1):

Hash the udf def from the system table:

```
SELECT md5(prosrc), *
from pg_proc
```

Comment: So if the udf name is `formatter` as in this case,


 `SELECT md5(formatter), *
    from pg_proc`


What is the * (asterix) in the select for ?